# asp:gridview filter using listbox cannot make multiple selection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

I have this asp:gridview in which I show data using mySql stored procedure. I have this listbox named ddlstatus which I use to filter the data. I use viewstate to show data that are selected from the listbox. The problem is I want to make multiple selection on this listbox and show data for each selection made on it, but when it only shows data for the initial selection.

The below is the client side code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblstat" Text="status" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlstatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownChange" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:GridView ID="gdvTM" runat="server" ControlStyle-Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDeleting="gdvTM_RowDeleting" PageSize="5" CssClass="cssgridview" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#d5d8dc">
    <Columns >
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Status">
         <ItemTemplate >
             <asp:Label ID="lblcstat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The below is the server side code:

```
private void BindDropDownList()
{
    PopulateDropDown(ddlstatus, lblstat.Text);
}
private void PopulateDropDown(ListBox ddl, string columnName)
{
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    ddl.DataSource = BindDropDown(columnName);
    ddl.DataTextField = columnName;
    ddl.DataValueField = columnName;
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", "0"));
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetTMData");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    string statusVal = null;
    if (ViewState["stat"] != null && ViewState["stat"].ToString() != "0")
    {
        statusVal = ViewState["stat"].ToString();
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("statusVal", statusVal);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gdvTM.DataSource = dt;
    int i = dt.Rows.Count;
    gdvTM.DataBind();
    this.BindDropDownList();
    TableCell cell = gdvTM.HeaderRow.Cells[0];
    setDropdownselectedItem(ViewState["stat"] != null ? (string)ViewState["stat"] : string.Empty, ddlstatus);
}
private void setDropdownselectedItem(string selectedvalue, ListBox ddl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedvalue))
    {
         ddl.Items.FindByValue(selectedvalue).Selected = true;

    }
}
protected void DropDownChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ListBox dropdown = (ListBox)sender;
      string selectedValue = dropdown.SelectedItem.Value;
      switch (dropdown.ID.ToLower())
      {
          case "ddlstatus":
             ViewState["stat"] = selectedValue;
             break;
      }

      this.BindGrid();
 }

private DataTable BindDropDown(string columnName)
{
    string username = uName.Text;
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT (" + columnName + ") FROM approved WHERE tm = @tm AND " + columnName + " IS NOT NULL", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", username);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Below is the MySql stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTMData`(in statusVal varchar(45))
BEGIN
SELECT *
   FROM approved
   WHERE (statusVal IS NULL
                OR status = statusVal)
         order by date desc;
END
```

How can I make this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that means if you choose four item in listbox then you receive only first item value on line `string selectedValue = dropdown.SelectedItem.Value;` in `DropDownChange` event handler right? and then data load for this item only

Comment: @er-sho yes and also after the postback the other three items are not selected on the list

Comment: do you know how to pass multiple values to single parameter in stored procedure for example if i select `a`, `b`, `c` then those will be pass in your SP with `statusVal` parameter?

Comment: @er-sho yeah we have to use IN right? but can we do it using foreach(ListItem Item1 in ddlstatus.items){} instead?

Comment: so how is the input need for this `statusVal` paramter? means its array like `["a", "b", "c"]` or only string like `a, b, c` ?

Comment: @er-sho normal string only

Comment: @er-sho ok bro :)

Comment: Show us the generated SQL; I think that will make the problem obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, auto post back not allow you to select multiple items because upto select second item, the postback already happens by first selected item so,

You have to set `AutoPostBack="false"` for your list box,

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlstatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

For collecting multiple selected items we simply choose button for instance, you can collect those items wherever you want,

Then add one button that will call below code

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="button1_Click" Text="Click"/>
```

On above button event handler add below code,

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedNames = ddlstatus.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                         .Where(i => i.Selected)
                         .Select(i => i.Value)
                         .ToList();

    string selectedValue = string.Join("','", selectedNames);

    selectedValue = "'" + selectedValue + "'";

    ViewState["stat"] = selectedValue;
}
```

Then the comma separated items in your `ViewState` will be used in your stored procedure parameter

```
string statusVal = null;
if (ViewState["stat"] != null && ViewState["stat"].ToString() != "0")
{
    statusVal = ViewState["stat"].ToString();
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("statusVal", statusVal);  //<= Now this string variable contains comma separated list box items values.
```

If you populate your list box on `Page_Load` then make sure that you should populate it into `!Page.IsPostBack` like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Populate your list box here
    }
}
```

And your SP is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTMData1`(in statusVal varchar(255))
BEGIN

IF statusVal = '\'\'' THEN 
   select * from approved;
ELSE
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM approved WHERE status IN (', statusVal, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;    
END IF ;        
END
```

If you select multiple items from the dropdown then your SP's parameter data look like `'\'apple\',\'banana\''`. If not then it look like `'\''`.

Comment: Did u receive multiple values in button click? Add breakpoint on line => var selectedNames..

Comment: I'm getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Error On which line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189195/discussion-between-prkash-and-er-sho).

Comment: Does string array pass to SP parameter?

Comment: Hey bro can we connect on this today?

Comment: @prkash, Oh your comment not appear in my notification so I didn't noticed. And yes we can connect tomorrow but some people downvote my answer. So I'll delete it after your problem solved.

Comment: When applying the above SP for multiple dropdownlist filtering, I will have to create so many number of combinations for this to work, still need to find a way to achieve the same for multiple dropdowns

Comment: Yes I think number of combination is must for it but  does SP works for multiple combinations ?

Comment: I think if you post on SO then probably you'll get better answer from my-sql guys. because its complicate SP to write for us. Any expert will give you some better solution

Comment: If you plan to post on SO then mention that what we did yesterday with SP with single parameter and want to do same with multiple paramter.

Comment: ok bro, I'm trying something different now, instead of using SP I'm writing the query on code. I'll update you how goes

Comment: Bro this method seems to work, but there is a minor problem, can we connect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569672/populating-mysql-data-to-asp-calendar-takes-too-long-to-load/55570528#55570528

Answer (score 3):

Please make listbox multiple

```
<asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
           Rows="6"
           Width="100px"
           **SelectionMode="Multiple"** 
           runat="server">

         <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>

      </asp:ListBox>
```

Then in server side 
void SubmitBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {

```
     Message.Text = "You chose: <br />";

     // Iterate through the Items collection of the ListBox and 
     // display the selected items.
     foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
     {

        if(item.Selected)
        {

           Message.Text += item.Text + "<br />";

        }

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues that I could spot that may need to be addressed,

1. Ensure that the method `BindDropDownList` is only called on a non postback (page refresh), because your method `PopulateDropDown` is clearing the items on the list which means that viewstate cannot be restored in a postback, hence the probable reason why only one item is being selected.
2. I'm not 100% of the table schema, but the SQL provided does not seem to be able to query by more than one status properly, you should probably send a comma separated list of values, and in SQL turn them into a temp table so that you effectively search for items with multiple status (you should probably create a new question for this).
3. Do not use `SelectedItem` for multiple selections, instead you need to iterate your list items for those that are selected, and you don't need to use `ViewState` to pass it along (you probably did because of point 1. above). For example you could replace your method `BindGrid` and `DropDownChange` with:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetTMData");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    string statusVal = null;
     foreach (ListItem item in ddlstatus.Items)
     {
        if(item.Selected)
        {
           if(statusVal.length > 0)
               statusVal += ",";
           statusVal += item.Value;
        }
     }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("statusVal", statusVal);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gdvTM.DataSource = dt;
    gdvTM.DataBind();

}

protected void DropDownChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      this.BindGrid();
 }
```

Comment: sorry you're right, I was hoping my answer would clarify the downvote. Basically, you don't need to change the UI (add a button, and disable autopostback on the list) if the actual main issue is addressed, the dropdown being rebound on a post back (1.) and that on your answer you kept using the viewstate to pass the status value is also an unnecessary overhead (and viewstate size) and you failed to address the issue with the procedure (2.) as it's mysql I don't have a specific answer, but i'm sure someone else will.

Comment: I gave a solution like on my answer to OP's problem after analyzing full source code via remote access through TeamViewer. The viewstate is mandatory for him. I think you should undownvote my answer. Because you'd give a solution on primary based and straightforward approach without knowing OP's full source code. :)