# Populating Mysql Data to asp calendar takes too long to load

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, fullcalendar, sqldatareader

I'm creating a leave calendar for employees, And for that I'm populating some data onto the calendar using `dataset`, but it takes too long to load the data.

I'm using multiple `MySqlDataReader` and `connections` to read the data from MySql table for each row of the calendar table. Maybe using multiple connections and readers might be the cause of slowing down but I'm not sure. The below is the code I use to populate the data.

```
class Sample
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string SlotAvailable { get; set; }
        public string Pending { get; set; }
        public string HeadCount { get; set; }
    }
    DateTime firstDate { get; set; }
    DateTime lastDate { get; set; }
    List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
    protected DataSet dsleaveplanner;
    protected void FillLeaveplannerDataset()
    {
        cal2.VisibleDate = cal2.TodaysDate;
        DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(cal2.VisibleDate.Year, cal2.VisibleDate.Month, 1).AddDays(-6);
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(cal2.VisibleDate.Date.AddMonths(1).Year, cal2.VisibleDate.Date.AddMonths(1).Month, 1).AddDays(7);
        dsleaveplanner = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
    }
    protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
    {
        int monthNumber, yearNumber;
        if (cal2.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
        {
            monthNumber = 1;
            yearNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            monthNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
            yearNumber = cal2.VisibleDate.Year;
        }
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
        return lastDate;
    }
    protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
    {
        string site = lblsite.Text;
        string skill = lblskill.Text;
        string shift = lblshift.Text;
        DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();
        string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        string caldate = "Select * From setshrinkage Where date >= @firstDate And date <= @lastDate And site=@site And skill=@skill And shift=@shift Group By date";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(caldate, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstDate", firstDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastDate", lastDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site", site);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill", skill);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shift", shift);
        MySqlDataAdapter mysqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        try
        {
            mysqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);
            con.Close();
        }

        catch { }
        return dsMonth;

    }
    public void caldisp(DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.NewLine.ToString();
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Slot available:"));
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(samples.Where(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date).FirstOrDefault().SlotAvailable.ToString()));
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p></p>Pending:"));
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(samples.Where(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date).FirstOrDefault().Pending.ToString()));
    }


    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime nextDate;
        //e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        if (dsleaveplanner != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsleaveplanner.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];
                var hcount = (dr["headCount"].ToString());
                Int32 hcount1 = Convert.ToInt32(hcount);
                string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                string cntdate = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM approved WHERE date = @date And site=@site And skill=@skill And shift=@shift And status=@status";
                string cntdate2 = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM approved WHERE date = @date And site=@site And skill=@skill And shift=@shift And status=@status";
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate, conn);
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(cntdate2, conn);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site", lblsite.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill", lblskill.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shift", lblshift.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "auto-approved");
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site", lblsite.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill", lblskill.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shift", lblshift.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "pending");
                string chklog = "SELECT date FROM approved WHERE date = @date And agentlogin=@login And status=@stat";
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(chklog, conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "auto-approved");
                conn.Open();
                string count = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                string count2 = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                var slot2 = Convert.ToInt32(count);
                Int32 slot3 = hcount1 - slot2;
                string slot4 = slot3.ToString();
                MySqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                string chklog1 = "SELECT date FROM approved WHERE date = @date And agentlogin=@login And status=@stat";
                MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(chklog1, con);
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
                cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "pending");
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
                MySqlConnection con2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                string chklog2 = "SELECT date FROM approved WHERE date = @date And agentlogin=@login And status=@stat";
                MySqlCommand cmd5 = new MySqlCommand(chklog2, con2);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "rejected");
                con2.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr3 = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                MySqlConnection con3 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                string chklog3 = "SELECT date FROM approved WHERE date = @date And agentlogin=@login And status=@stat";
                MySqlCommand cmd6 = new MySqlCommand(chklog3, con3);
                cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", nextDate);
                cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
                cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "agent-withdrawn");
                con3.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr4= cmd6.ExecuteReader();
                if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
                {
                    if (dr1.HasRows)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                    }
                    else if (dr2.HasRows)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
                    }
                    else if (dr3.HasRows)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
                    }
                    else if (dr4.HasRows)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkTurquoise;
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                con.Close();
                con2.Close();
                con3.Close();
                samples.Add(new Sample { Date = nextDate, SlotAvailable = slot4, Pending = count2 });
            }
            if (samples.Any(x => x.Date == e.Day.Date))
            {
                string weekoff = lblweekoff.Text;
                List<string> offday = (lblweekoff.Text).Split(',').ToList();
                if (offday.Contains(e.Day.Date.ToString("ddd")))
                {
                    e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Week-Off </p>"));
                }
                else
                {
                    caldisp(e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Target not set! </p>"));
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make this process faster? Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of individual queries for each date, surely you could just retrieve all data within a range of dates (e.g. the range of dates that are going to be displayed on the calendar)

Comment: You also appear to run the same query multiple times, varying only the "stat" parameter. This is very inefficient. Instead, you can use a SQL "IN" clause to allow you to select rows which contain any one of a set of values. I think potentially the problem you've run into here is that you need to learn some more SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 6 SQL queries into foreach statement, if you have 10 rows in dsleaveplanner the program will execute 60 SQL queries. this number of SQL queries will have a negative impact on performance.
try to retrieve all data before your foreach statement and stock data into lists (memory) then use it within your foreach

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is the very first line in the foreach loop `nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];`, I have to use this value as a parameter for all the queries. This Value can be obtained only from inside the foreach loop. If there is any way to get this value before the loop, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: I'm agree with you but before foreach you can retrieve all data into list then filter the list into the foreach